# Warning while executing the SSIS package

Tags: ssis

> [SSIS.Pipeline] Warning: The output column "Worker ID" (36) on output
>   "Excel Source Output" (9) and component "Excel Source" (1) is not
>   subsequently used in the Data Flow task. Removing this unused output
>   column can increase Data Flow task performance.

While importing the data from excel sheet to DB, getting the above warning after executing the package. The warning is not only for "Worker ID" but for all the columns(7 columns) present in excel sheet. Anyone please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you inserting all columns in DB? The Warning says you are selecting columns from excel that you are not inserting in destination (DB)

Answer (score 0):

Open the advanced properties of "Excel Source", and delete the columns that are mentioned in the warnings from the output.